# ODP.net filter not applying in EF model designer

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, odp.net

I'm currently trying to add an entity from another oracle schemas into my EDMX model. So I added the needed schemas into the connexion filter settings. It shows well in the server explorer (however it seem to reset at each VS restart).

However, when I launch the "update model from database" wizard, it don't  show me the other shemas table at all. I even tried with a synonyme but with no more success. I know I can create a view of my table but I feel a little bit unconfortable creating a foreign key pointing to a view (I'm not even sure it's possible)

I'm using the lastest ODAC/ODP.net libraries (12c update 3 (4.121.2.0)) and EF (6)

So, long story short :

- Is there a way to add another shemas table as entity trought the model desinger ? (or any other way)

Comment: Check the "Filters" tab on the connection dialog in Server Explorer. By default, it will not show other schemas and you will need to add the other schema. Also, are you using an ASP.NET project?

Comment: Yes it's an ASP.net and I tried to change the filter in the connexion settings but it seem to only affect the server explorer (ie, no effect in the update from DB wizzard. Also, those filters seem to reset as soon as I restart visual. I tried to locate the file containit those filter without success...

Comment: ASP.NET projects have a known problem: the Server Explorer connection used by the project will get renamed and when you close the project this Server Explorer connection will be deleted by the project. When you reopen the project, the project will create and add a new Server Explorer connection and so the Filters info has to be redone by the user. Please make sure that when you reopen a project, you recreate the filter every time.

Comment: The main problem isn't the reset (altrought it can be somewhat annoying) but the fact that the filter are totally ignored by the model designer. Even if i set the schemas name filter to a single other schemas, the wizard will still list me the main schemas tables/views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved the problem, the Oracle developper tools for visual studio where not totally up to date.

The installation of the lastest update 3 solved the problem, the schemas now shows in the model desinger

Comment: What about filter persistence? Is it still an issue in old version?

Comment: It is still an issue in current version. I almost lost half a model mapping a few days ago because of that (my git repo saved me by allowing me to rollback the failed model update)

Comment: It's about time (it's been at least 5 years) that Oracle would make those filters persistent.

Comment: I'm not sur if the problem is from the oracle ODP or from VS itself for this ... Anyway, let's wait and see ...

Comment: This happened to me as well. Very annoying, and it still doesn't seem to be fixed. Has anyone come up with a solution yet?  If you forget to re-add the Schema in the filter of the connection, you are in a world of hurt!

Comment: I have the same problem, and I even added a thread on Oracle's forum asking about it: https://community.oracle.com/thread/4083749